# some button on keyboard suddenly stops working properly

Tags: keyboard, asus-laptop

My laptop is not so old (2 years), I use few hours a day (1-2 hours) it's an Asus F552CL. Suddenly some key stop working properly, as you can see from the image some key probably I've never used (the num pad for example), or used really few times (I.e. ESC key) and are almost all on the same line.

[image]

- The problem doesn't seems an OS related problem, since it act the same way inside the BIOS too.
- The keyboard driver seems to works properly
- External keyboards works well

What can be? There's a way to spot this time of problems and try to resolve it on my own.

Comment: It sounds like a hardware problem. See if your laptop still is under warranty and get it replaced. If not, you may want to look into getting the keyboard part replaced. Should be around 50-80$

Comment: I goes to an Asus lab and they asked me a lot (almost 200$) for a laptop payed less than 370$ 3yrs ago? So I should replace it, but what part should I replace? Connectors? Keyboard? Hardware components seems OK (i.e. keys doesn't jam) and sometimes they work for few seconds. Could it be the connectors?

Comment: I'm not an ASUS tech specialist. If they charge 200$ for it, it seems there's more going on than just the keyboard. If the laptop is not under warranty, you may want to consider buying a completely new laptop, or buy a cheap small external keyboard with a usb receiver that is so small that you can keep it in one of the usb ports permanently.

Comment: As test I have asked how much for an additional 4GB ram block and they ask me 70$, maybe there's an upward trend...

Comment: Could be. Maybe you can get better prices from a third party.